# idiomatic scala/FP way of expressing similar value objects

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am wondering what is the idiomatic way to express similar messages (value objects) 
Let's say I have some messages that I want to send : UserEnter, UserLeft, UserSendGreeting etc'. I hope that the following can express my dilemma

there are two options that I think one can express it :

```
trait UserAction
case class UserEnter (username:String,hour:Long,day:WeekDay,room:Int)
case class UserLeft (username:String,hour:Long,day:WeekDay,room:Int)
case class UserSendGreeting (username:String,,hour:Long,day:WeekDay,greeting:String)

def foo(userActions:List[UserAction]) = {
userActions match {
case UserEnter(userName)::tail =>
sendWelcomeMessage(userName)
handleOtherActions(tail) 

case UserLeft::tail => "must enter first"
case _ => "do something else"
}
```

another way is :

```
    trait Action
    case class Enter(room:Int) extends Action
    case object Left(room:Int) extends Action
    case object Greet(msg:String) extends Action

    case class UserAction(username:String,action:Action,,hour:Long,day:WeekDay)

    def foo(userActions:List[UserAction]) = {
    userActions match {
    case head::tail if head.action == Enter =>
    sendWelcomeMessage(head.userName)    
    handleOtherActions(tail)             
    case head::tail if head.action == Left => "must enter first"
    case _ => "do something else"
    }
```

The 1st option is more explicit and easier to pattern match but more repetitive code. 
The other one is more explicit on the action itself but pattern match is more verbose
which way is better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things. If you need to have a pair of `User` (in your case string name) and `Action`, use `Tuple`. Also it makes sense to gather all "...other attributes" inside corresponding `Action`.

```
type User = String

sealed trait Action

case class Enter(room:Int) extends Action

case class Left(room:Int) extends Action

case class Greet(msg:String) extends Action


def foo(userActions:List[(User, Action)]) = userActions match {
    case (username, _:Enter)::tail =>
      sendWelcomeMessage(username)
      handleOtherActions(tail)
    case (username, _:Left)::tail => "must enter first"
    case _ => "do something else"
  }
```

Also don't forget, that pattern matching allows you to `unapply` hierarchies of arbitrary depth:

```
case (username, Enter(room))::tail =>
```

Comment: Parten me for my ignorance, but what does `::tail` do in this case?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov this is `List` decomposition into `head` and `tail`. Check `scala.collection.immutable.::` case class (it's basically call of its `unapply` method).

Comment: @Aivean speaking of "bad approaches", don't use tuples unless you have to. Tuples = bad. Case classes = good

Comment: @Dima, can you elaborate, why "Tuples=bad"? In particular for the case when you need to bind a pair of two loosely related objects together.

Comment: @Aivean They are bad, because they are the same as case classes minus the readability.

Comment: @Dima I think that type `(User, Action)` is more concise and readable  than `case class UserAction(user:User, action:Action)`, but I really don't want to spend my time further arguing about it. Peace!

Comment: The _type_ may be readable. The code, that uses it, is not. `if (x._2._1 > 3 && x._1._3 < 18) println("Action is not allowed.").` 
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the 1 way is better but you can make a constraint on UserAction trait to have username field:

```
trait UserAction {
  def username: String
}
case class UserEnter(username:String, room:Int)
case class UserLeft(username:String, room:Int)
case class UserSendGreeting(username:String, greeting:String)
```

This way it is easy to

1) pattern match

2) use generic `UserAction` to get username field

Answer (score 0):

How about: `case class UserAction(user: User, action: Action)`

```
def foo(actions: Seq[UserActions]) = actions match {
    case UserAction(user, _: EnterAction)::tail => 
      processEnter(user)
      handleOtherActions(tail)
    case UserExit(user, _: ExitAction)::tail => processExit(user)
    ...
}
```

Or even better

```
def foo(actions: Seq[UserAction]) = actions.find { ua => 
  !ua.action.process(ua.user)
}
```

Or, maybe, just

```
def foo(action: Seq[UserAction]) = actions.find { !_.process }
```

Comment: `action.process(...)` is not good approach. It clearly comes from OOP world, where you are encouraged to couple data and logic. But even in OOD this particular example is a bad practice, as `process`  affects the outer state, not only the internal state of `Action`. Also imagine that you have several different places where `Actions` are handled. Will you create separate `process` method inside the `Action` for each such case? Do `Actions` really need to be aware of each handler?

Comment: @Aivean: 1. just because something "comes from OOP world" doesn't mean "it is not a good approach" ;) 2. You don't know which state `process` affects. But, if we speculate, that it affects, say, the state of the system console ... would you then argue it should be a method on a system console? I hope not. 3. Imagine 148 different handlers ... and now you want to add a new action. Do all the handlers need to be aware of that? ;)
Bottomline, either approach is valid, which one is better depends on the details of a particular use case. This is not a religious question.